# Custom Properties a la Rigify (Global Properties?)

Tags: rigging, properties

So the Rigify Rigs have custom properties that can be tweaked no matter what bone you have selected in pose mode.

However I've been unable to make my own. Adding custom properties under the Armature tab for the rig don't seem to show up... anywhere really. Adding properties from the bone tab causes the property to only show up when that specific bone is selected, which isn't ideal if you're using the property to drive several bones for example.

How would I go about creating these 'global' properties for the armature so that I can use them no matter what bone is selected in pose mode?

Comment: The Rigify UI is created by a python script which creates the UI controls and property from absolute data paths connecting them with the rigs properties.